# Spreadsheet (Excel, Google Docs etc), extracting value separated by comma

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a value in one cell that looks like this

```
4,8,2
```

Lets say it's in the `A1` cell

how I can get the inner `8` (the second comma separated value) from this cell into the cell B1 ?

`=?`

Tried with `=SPLIT(A1, ",")`, but this splits the values and writes them to multiple cells.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Will each cell of this type have exactly three comma delimited numbers?

Comment: yes, all single digit from 1 to 8

Comment: You could also try the "text to column" function in Excel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Google Sheets:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,","),2)
```

Where the `2` is the index you want.

[image]

---

In Excel:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(2-1)*999+1,999))
```

Or this array formula:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),2)
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter Instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Again replace the `2` with the desired index.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: What's the reason behind using `REPT`? and `999` here?

Comment: It is giving me a large target to hit. 999 spaces that the trim then removes.

Answer (score 5):

4,8,2

Formulas for each number.

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH(",",A1,1)-1)
=MID(A1, SEARCH(",",A1) + 1, SEARCH(",",A1,SEARCH(",",A1)+1) - SEARCH(",",A1) - 1)
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1) - SEARCH(",", A1, SEARCH(",", A1) + 1))
```

Source: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/01/split-text-string-excel/

Note: This will only work for three comma delimited numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mid in Excel, the following formula will find the first "," and second "," to extract the value between it:
`=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1,FIND(",",SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ",1),1)-1-FIND(",",A1,1))`
whatever the value is one or more digits